# Samsung a40 bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking

Does anyone know how to fix a bootloop? I have tried flashing a stock room using Heimdall but that only makes the phone show to Samsung logo show the erasing animation for a little bit and boots into download mode and show "Error validating footer (6)"   . If I try to generate a vbmeta file with abvtool it shows the warning that says that unofficial software was installed and shows the unlocked bootloader warning and after that it reboots.

Comment: @alecxs Where should I find that file?

Comment: @alecxs After un tarring the stock ROM. I found only a "vbmeta.img" file and no "vbmeta_samsung.img". Could this be because I downloaded the firmware from "samfw.com"?

Comment: @alecxs So if that does not apply to my phone is there any other way to unbrick my phone or should I just try to flash "vbmeta_samsung.img" even if it is for another phone or version?

Comment: @alecxs But after flashing TWRP all the phone does is show to unofficial software was installed, show the unlocked bootloader warning and reboot.

Comment: of course easy way is flash stock ROM but it will re-lock bootloader and you might not able to unlock again because of samsungs restrictions. you can install [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4025587) and [AOSP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4004673) instead

Comment: read the instructions and ask in that threads if something is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Samsung Smart Switch app for PC to restore the stock ROM.